# Jquery run after plugin

Tags: magento-2.1, javascript, jquery, requirejs

I use a third-party theme, initially the theme included Jquery through `default_head_blocks.xml`. I wanted to use requireJS instead and I removed Jquery from `default_head_blocks.xml`.

Now I have this error:

> jQuery is not defined

I found that jquery is loaded after his plugins. How can I load jquery just after `requirejs-config.js` ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to include Jquery as a dependecy of all your scripts that require it. How are they included?

If these are AMD modules you must have, for example in `in.js:`

```
define(['jquery'], function($){

     // The script

});
```